# How do you preform a distance calculation and get answer to display in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, computer-science

I can't figure out how to make the formula the instructor gave to work and display and answer. The formula he gave was:

```
distance = Math.sqrt( ( (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) ) + ( (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) ) );
```

Comment: It looks like homework. Right?

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <title>Home Lab 4</title>
    <head>
 </head>
<body>
    
       <script type="text/javascript">
function distance()
{
distance=Math.sqrt( ( (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) ) + ( (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) ) );
}
</script>
   <br>
     <input type="button" onclick="distance()" value="distance">
</body>
</html>

Comment: There is also a table in the body to input values for x1,x2,y1, and y2.

Answer (score 0):

It's `(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)`, not `(x2-x1)*(c2-x1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is wrong. The correct one is: sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y2)^2 )

```
// Two points to find the distance between
var a = [564,426];
var b = [56,784];

// subtract the x's and square the result
var xN = Math.pow( b[0] - a[0], 2 );

// subtract the y's and square the result
var yN = Math.pow( b[1] - a[1], 2 );

// Add the two results together then find their square root
var distance = Math.sqrt(xN + yN);
```

Resource: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php